# The option - Source hover background is missing in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, customization, eclipse-kepler

**Eclipse kepler** doesn't show the option to change the - 'Source hover background' for the tool tip which pops up on CTRL+Hover on a function call that shows the function definition. I am stuck as the 'Source hover background' option is missing in eclipse kepler under - window->preferences. An image is attached for easy reference. Thanks in advance.[image: an image is attached for easy reference].

Comment: What programming language? The configuration may be in `Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts`

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Hello greg-449, I have tried all the option under - Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts but couldn't find it out.

Comment: Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130614-0229
I am using eclipse Kepler for PHP (with PDT) in windows.

Comment: Is this a regression from 3.x or is this a new feature request to add such a preference ?

Comment: Hello Eric, this is neither a regression nor a new feature request. It is rather an existing functionality that behaves in an undesirable manner.